# How to architecture business layer or wcf ria services

Tags: silverlight, wcf, architecture, ria

We are building a new system from scratch and have decided on SL4, WCF RIA Services and EF4.

So I see the WCF RIA services as the business logic of the SL client, but can it be used as a general business logic layer, that can be used by other parts of the application. As an example the WCF RIA service will have security implemented (such as who is allowed to do what with which objects). But this security implementation should also be by other parts of the system and not only by the SL client.

To avoid having this logic duplicated my idea is to use the WCF RIA service as a general business layer meaning that if other parts of the system needs access to the datalayer they would need to go through this layer.

But is this an ok usage of WCF RIA?

Thanks

Comment: We have decided to use the RIA services layer only as a service layer to the Silverlight client. Other parts of the system must access the data layer through another business layer. This will allows to us to have some custom business rules for the SL client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is the standard WCF RIA pattern and is how the WCF RIA team designed the system to work.

WCF RIA will allow you to get end-to-end access to your EF4 entities and hide your business logic behind the RIA service interface. You can apply authentication and authorization attributes to your entities in the service definition (domain service class) at either the class level (all methods in the service contract) or the method level for more granular control.

The only major flaw I see in your plan is "other parts of the system needs access to the datalayer they would need to go through this layer". WCF RIA at this stage only plays well with Silverlight (and maybe ASP.NET MVC? I am not sure). Microsoft eventually intends to extend RIA Services to be consumed by any kind of .NET application but at this stage it's really a Silverlight-only thing. This means that you'll miss out on a lot of the WCF RIA goodies with your other non-Silverlight applications. However I believe you can still expose the WCF RIA service as an ordinary WCF service, including the authentication/authorization layer. You'll just miss out on the automatic proxies, code generation, etc.

There are still several ways of using this service layer from outside of Silverlight however. You can expose your EF4 entities with an OData endpoint or SOAP/REST service. For more details on this, check out [this article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-10-Exposing-Domain-Services-To-Other-Clients.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In the big RIA project we usually have so many modules ( Business modules, licensing, authorization,  Audit modules etc.) and obviously there are some modules that need to be accessed across other modules and also some across the SL client. So I believe your concern is a typical architecture side on how you make this properly distribute in a big application. As in any .NET project, you can modularize it in to different library projects. That means you can appropriately make some as [RIA Service Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707351%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) project or else typical reusable .net libraries ( for example, Logging library)